Why is the cross ratio for four points on a conic different for each conic passing through the four points?
"First assume that the points $1, 2, 3, 4$ are fixed. The previous theorem (10.1) states
that for a fixed conic C, the value of $(1, 2; 3, 4)_p$ is independent of the choice
of $p$. Thus it can be considered as a characteristic number that singles out
the specific conic C from all other conics through the four points. Thus we
can take this number as a kind of coordinate for the conic within the onedimensional bundle of conics through 1, 2, 3, 4. In fact, if we do so the three
special degenerate conics in this bundle (compare Figure 10.1) correspond to
the values 0, 1, and ∞." - Perspectives on Projective geometry p. 172.
But I am wondering why this is this case. Why can't two distinct conics passing through these four points give the same cross ratio?

Condition $(*)$ at the beginning of § 10.2 "characterizes whether six points are on a conic". That means that if $(1,2;3,4)_p=(1,2;3,4)_q$, then $p$ and $q$ lie on the same conic, and vice versa.

@Intelligentipauca I didn't read that part carefully enough...

One way to see that claim is by recovering the equation of the conic from that cross ratio. Ignoring the case of infinity as the value of the cross ratio, you get this:
\begin{align*}
(1,2;3,4)_p&=\lambda\\
\frac{[1,3,p][2,4,p]}{[1,4,p][2,3,p]}&=\lambda\\
[1,3,p][2,4,p]&=\lambda[1,4,p][2,3,p]\\
[1,3,p][2,4,p]-\lambda[1,4,p][2,3,p]&=0
\end{align*}
Since every square bracket denotes a determinant, each of them is linear in $p$, so the whole equation is quadratic in $p$.
So for for given representatives of the four given points, you get exactly one equation. If you pick different scalar multiples of the homogeneous coordinates of one or more of the points, you get scalar multiples of the equation which still represent the same conic.
Now if you have a different conic, that conic has to have an equation which is substantially different, not just by a scalar factor on the whole homogeneous equation. So that has to corresponds to a different cross ratio, too.
